# Python urllib.request.urlopen omitted contents

Tags: web-crawler, urlopen

While I was getting the images from the architecture image site by using Python urllib, I met a problem.

When I used the `urllib.request.urlopen` function, some information that I precisely want to take is omitted and modified. It especially occurred in image "src" part.

I just want to get the same html strings. Is there any way to solve the problem ?

The problem part is as below image:

[image]

Comment: The content is probably generated dynamically with JS.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the welcome tour to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [mcve] example and also check [ask] so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.